# iOS swift not able to design weekly calendar , i have shared screenshot of UI which i want in my app

Tags: ios, swift

[image]want to design a custom calendar.I have shared screenshot. I searched so many but all did not full-fill my requirement. There is one dropdown option for selection month. According to selected month i have to manage the UI.

Comment: https://ibb.co/D5J7ZP0

Comment: there are many calendar UI ready to use.you can pick the one most similar to your case and change their source code,not that hard.I recommand FSCalendar https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: ya i have used CvCalender for this, but i am not able to open specific month. Can u help me out how can i open specific month from that???

Comment: it is not that difficult to read the source code and change it adaptable to what you want.